# Using Javascript to get URL Vars, not working when multiple values present in QueryString

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string

I am using a Javascript function to get the values of a URL to pass to jQuery using the function below:

```
 function getUrlVars()
    {
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
        {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[0]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
    return vars;
    }
```

And then setting the value like this:

```
 var type = getUrlVars()["type"]
```

This all works perfectly, however I have just come into a situation where I need to get multiple values, one of my form elements are checkboxes where multiple values can be checked, so my URL will look something like this:

```
 http://www.domain.com/test.php?type=1&cuisine[]=23&cuisine[]=43&name=test
```

If I alert out the cuisine value using the function above I only ever get the final value:

```
 alert (getUrlVars()["cuisine[]"]);
```

Would alert "43".

What I would like it to be is a comma delimited string of all "cuisine" values. ie in the above example "23,43"

Any help very welcome! In case any solution requires it I am using PHP 5.3 and Jquery 1.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    function getUrlVars()
    {
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
        {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');

            if($.inArray(hash[0], vars)>-1)
            {
                vars[hash[0]]+=","+hash[1];
            }
            else
            {
                vars.push(hash[0]);
                vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
            }
        }

        return vars;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to check in you for loop if vars[hash[0]] already exists and if so then instead of doing vars[hash[0]] = hash[1]; you'll do vars[hash[0]] += ',' + hash[1];

Answer (score 1):

A more proper solution, as the query string *should* have unique keys is to add a hidden field  to the form, and then in the `onsubmit` event you loop over the checkboxes and set the value of the hidden field to the aggregated values form the checkboxes.

The script

```
function getValues(){
    var inputs= document.getElementById("myForm").getElementsByTagName("input"), i=inputs.length;
    var values=[];
    while (i--){
        if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox" && inputs[i].checked) {
            values.push(inputs[i].value);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("hiddenField").value=values.join();
}
```

And the HTML

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="getValues()">
<input type="hidden" name="values" id="hiddenField"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" value="2"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

This is better than overriding the default (and expected behavior) of key/value based parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object)