# Get value from url with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a programmes page which contains tags and subcategories. On clicking a tag, the url of the page changes to something like this:

```
localhost:3000/programmes/global-entrances/gre?tag_id=2&url=%2Ftag_sort%2F2%3Fcategory%3Dgre
```

Based on which tag has been clicked I want to change the tag color, so I need to get the tag_id value from the url.

First I checked whether the url contains a string called `tag_id` by doing this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url      = window.location.href; 
    substring = "tag_id";
    if(url.indexOf(substring) > -1){
          // if true then get the tag_id value 
    }
});
```

Now I got stuck with it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849415/using-javascript-to-get-url-vars-not-working-when-multiple-values-present-in-qu

Comment: I think you might be looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: do you need to get the value of tag_id?

Comment: FYI params in the URL, starting with `?` are available as `location.search`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the shortcut to get the value of `tag_id`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = "localhost:3000/programmes/global-entrances/gre?tag_id=2&url=%2Ftag_sort%2F2%3Fcategory%3Dgre";//window.location.href;
    var result = url.split("?")[1].split("&")[0].split("=")[1];
    alert(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

A jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/frayne_konok/ku7qg25v/), test it.

This is only the quick and shortcut solution, if its work for you then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

We need our good old friend RegEx for this.

First, we get the url of the page by doing document.location.href. This will give you the URL of the page, and for off-site testing purposes you can replace 'document.location.href' with the URL as a string.

The regex tests for 'tag_id=', any characters, then the ampersand which connects the next value. Then we strip 'tag_id=' from the result, and slice off the end '&' - leaving you with the value at the end.

```
    var url = document.location.href;
    var regEx = /(tag_id=).+?&/g;
    var value = (url.match(regEx));
    value = value[0].replace("tag_id=", "");
    value = value.slice(0, -1);
    console.log(value);
```

Comment: I should note that this will work for urls where 'tag_id' is not the last (or only) attribute passed by the URL.